# (1054, "Unknown column 'm' in 'field list'")

Tags: python

i have create a mysql table like----> create table test(gender char(1));

my python sudo code is---->

```
from pymysql import *
g='m'
sql='insert into test values(%s)' %g
cur.execute(sql)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

but its giving me error --->
(1054, "Unknown column 'm' in 'field list'")

plz help me out to solve it

Comment: The error message is quite explanatory. What are you not understanding?

Comment: I know that is not the answer, but Why don't you try to use a full "INSERT INTO test () VALUES ()" sentence?

Comment: chut marinaaa aise quesion nai dalte

Answer (score 3):

The

```
'insert into test values(%s)' %g
```

expands to

```
'insert into test values(m)'
```

which is clearly not what you want (what is `m`?)

My recommendation is to use bind parameters:

```
g = 'm'
sql = 'insert into test values(?)'
cur.execute(sql, g)
```

For more information, see [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

`'insert into test () values('%s')' %g
... this is because the variable g is a`String` and after the append that you are doing this must look like:

"insert into test () values('m')" and not "insert into test () values(m)"

<>

cheers